# Regex in python, Need to print website name from a string

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

x = 'my website name is www.algoexpert.com and i have other website too'
for line in x:
    y = line.rstrip()
z = re.findall('.*\S+/.[a-z]{0-9}/.\S+', y) 
print(z)
```

I just want to print the website name (`www.algoexpert.com`)

Comment: This is a bit broad. Do you just want  `www.something.com` or do you need to support stuff like `foo.something.tk`? What constitutes a "website name"? Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues to fix:

- `x` is a string itself, why are you looping over it with `for line in x`?
- `[a-z]{0-9}` - tries to cover only alphabetical chars, though in wrong way (could be `{0,9}`). The range of chars should be `[a-z0-9]+` or at least - `[a-z]+` (depending on the initial intention)
- dots/periods `.` should be escaped with backslash `\.`

Fixed version (simplified):

```
import re

x = 'my website name is www.algoexpert.com and i have other website too'
z = re.findall('\S+\.[a-z0-9]+\.\S+', x.strip())
print(z)   # ['www.algoexpert.com']
```

Comment: Actually x = open('file.txt'). I entered here wrong. That's why i looped it. I forget i gave it a string